# Modify macro to have \newtcbinputlisting caption different in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, tcolorbox, tcbinputlisting

I would like some help to get the caption of the below `\newtcbinputlisting` to show up differently in the TOC.  For example, for figure captions, the user can type

```
...
\caption[MakeMaze output]{MakeMaze output with a value of 10}%
...
```

Where "MakeMaze ouptput" appears in the TOC, and "MakeMaze output with a value of 10" appears as the figure caption.

The code below uses the command `\inputmatlab{Expansion Algorithm}{sample.m}`, where "Expansion Algorithm" will appear as the caption under the Matlab code.  I wanted to get a different caption to appear in the TOC.  Thansks!

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, oneside, fleqn, openright]{report}

\newcommand{\codeimg}{$\vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[height=\baselineskip]{example-image-a}}}$}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfpages,graphicx}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.92}
\definecolor{mygray}{RGB}{243,243,244}

\definecolor{mainColor}{RGB}{211, 47, 47}

\usepackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier}

\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Code}
\lstset{
    language=Python,
    numbers=left,
    numbersep= 7mm,
    numberstyle=\color{Black},
    stepnumber=1,
    tabsize=3,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    breaklines=true,
    captionpos=b,
    basicstyle=\color{Black}\ttfamily,
    commentstyle=\color{LimeGreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{BurntOrange}\bfseries,
    stringstyle=\color{WildStrawberry},
    keywords={var, func, extends},
    frame=leftline,
    framesep=0mm,
    xleftmargin=3mm,
    framesep=2mm, 
    framerule=0mm,
    abovecaptionskip=5mm,
    aboveskip=\baselineskip,
    belowskip=\baselineskip
}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newcounter{matlab}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable,listings}

\newtcbinputlisting[use counter=matlab,list inside=matlab,number within=chapter]{\inputmatlab}[3][]{%
        enhanced,noparskip,breakable,colback=light-gray,colframe=DarkSlateGray,opacitybacktitle=.8,%
        fonttitle=\bfseries,before upper={\hspace*{-1em}\codeimg~#3},%
    title after break={\centering\footnotesize\itshape\strut Matlab Code~\thematlab~--~continued},%
     listing only,listing options={xleftmargin=-1mm,#1,style=Matlab-editor,basicstyle=\ttfamily\small},
     after upper={\centering\strut {\bfseries Matlab Code~\thematlab:}~#2},
     frame hidden,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,boxrule=0pt,
     overlay={\draw[gray,line width=1mm] ([xshift=-0.5pt]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=-0.5pt]frame.south west);},
     %
     listing file={#3},#1}


\begin{filecontents*}{sample.m}
% create a file for output
!touch testFile.txt
fid = fopen('testFile.text', 'w')
for i=1:10
  fprintf(fid,'%6.2f \n', i);
end
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}

\inputmatlab{Expansion Algorithm}{sample.m}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your example does not use `\tcblistof{matlab}`  -- there's is nothing to list yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the quick method, use `list entry=#4` where `#4` is the alternative title for the caption designed for the code list.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, oneside, fleqn, openright]{report}

\newcommand{\codeimg}{$\vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[height=\baselineskip]{example-image-a}}}$}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfpages,graphicx}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.92}
\definecolor{mygray}{RGB}{243,243,244}

\definecolor{mainColor}{RGB}{211, 47, 47}

\usepackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier}

\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Code}
\lstset{
    language=Python,
    numbers=left,
    numbersep= 7mm,
    numberstyle=\color{Black},
    stepnumber=1,
    tabsize=3,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    breaklines=true,
    captionpos=b,
    basicstyle=\color{Black}\ttfamily,
    commentstyle=\color{LimeGreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{BurntOrange}\bfseries,
    stringstyle=\color{WildStrawberry},
    keywords={var, func, extends},
    frame=leftline,
    framesep=0mm,
    xleftmargin=3mm,
    framesep=2mm, 
    framerule=0mm,
    abovecaptionskip=5mm,
    aboveskip=\baselineskip,
    belowskip=\baselineskip
}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newcounter{matlab}

\newtcbinputlisting[use counter=matlab,list inside=matlab,number within=chapter]{\inputmatlab}[4][]{%
  enhanced,noparskip,breakable,colback=light-gray,colframe=DarkSlateGray,opacitybacktitle=.8,%
  fonttitle=\bfseries,before upper={\hspace*{-1em}\codeimg~#3},%
  title after break={\centering\footnotesize\itshape\strut Matlab Code~\thematlab~--~continued},%
  listing only,listing options={xleftmargin=-1mm,#1,style=Matlab-editor,basicstyle=\ttfamily\small},list entry=#4,
  after upper={\centering\strut {\bfseries Matlab Code~\thematlab:}~#2},
  frame hidden,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,boxrule=0pt,
  overlay={\draw[gray,line width=1mm] ([xshift=-0.5pt]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=-0.5pt]frame.south west);},
  % 
  listing file={#3},#1
}


\begin{filecontents*}{sample.m}
% create a file for output
!touch testFile.txt
fid = fopen('testFile.text', 'w')
for i=1:10
  fprintf(fid,'%6.2f \n', i);
end
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}
\tcblistof{matlab}{List of codes}
\inputmatlab{Expansion Algorithm}{sample.m}{This is foo}
\end{document}
```

**Update**

Better method with `\DeclareTCBInputListing`, allowing for improved optional argument support from `xparse`:

Usage `\inputmatlab[listing etc options]{Description}[optional description for list of matlab codes]{file name}`.

The `list entry` option by `tcolorbox` decides which content will be written to the relevant file, `.matlab` here. If `list entry` is unused, `tcolorbox` tries to use the value of the `title` option, if this not set also, the current box number and environment name is applied and stored to the file.

The order of the optional argument for the optional description is arbitrary as long as the relevant argument numbers are updated.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, oneside, fleqn, openright]{report}

\newcommand{\codeimg}{$\vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[height=\baselineskip]{example-image-a}}}$}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfpages,graphicx}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.92}
\definecolor{mygray}{RGB}{243,243,244}

\definecolor{mainColor}{RGB}{211, 47, 47}

\usepackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier}

\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Code}
\lstset{
    language=Python,
    numbers=left,
    numbersep= 7mm,
    numberstyle=\color{Black},
    stepnumber=1,
    tabsize=3,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    breaklines=true,
    captionpos=b,
    basicstyle=\color{Black}\ttfamily,
    commentstyle=\color{LimeGreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{BurntOrange}\bfseries,
    stringstyle=\color{WildStrawberry},
    keywords={var, func, extends},
    frame=leftline,
    framesep=0mm,
    xleftmargin=3mm,
    framesep=2mm, 
    framerule=0mm,
    abovecaptionskip=5mm,
    aboveskip=\baselineskip,
    belowskip=\baselineskip
}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newcounter{matlab}




\DeclareTCBInputListing[use counter=matlab,list inside=matlab,number within=chapter]{\inputmatlab}{O{}+m+O{#2}+m}{%
  enhanced,noparskip,breakable,colback=light-gray,colframe=DarkSlateGray,opacitybacktitle=.8,%
  fonttitle=\bfseries,before upper={\hspace*{-1em}\codeimg~#4},%
  title after break={\centering\footnotesize\itshape\strut Matlab Code~\thematlab~--~continued},%
  listing only,listing options={xleftmargin=-1mm,#1,style=Matlab-editor,basicstyle=\ttfamily\small},list entry=#3,
  after upper={\centering\strut {\bfseries Matlab Code~\thematlab:}~#2},
  frame hidden,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,boxrule=0pt,
  overlay={\draw[gray,line width=1mm] ([xshift=-0.5pt]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=-0.5pt]frame.south west);},
  % 
  listing file={#4},#1
}


\begin{filecontents*}{sample.m}
% create a file for output
!touch testFile.txt
fid = fopen('testFile.text', 'w')
for i=1:10
  fprintf(fid,'%6.2f \n', i);
end
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}
\tcblistof{matlab}{List of codes}
\inputmatlab{Expansion Algorithm}[Other title]{sample.m}
\end{document}
```

[image]